# Proving the graph norm is indeed a norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I was reading p.238-239 in the book
[enter link description here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=u9M9PFLNpMMC&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=show%20graph%20norm%20indeed%20a%20norm&source=bl&ots=64GsNajiOY&sig=BYEYxjNWRLeLhCF2cnjcOnFQLLo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis7u34sJTKAhUFW5QKHSLXCxMQ6AEIRDAI#v=onepage&q=show%20graph%20norm%20indeed%20a%20norm&f=false)
[image]

Example A.14 in that book motivates me to think of the following question.
And have trouble verifying the following fact from functional analysis.

Consider operators of the form $T: V\to \mathcal{E},$ where $V\subset E$ is a (not necessarily closed) linear subspace, which are linear. We say that $T$ is densely defined if $V$ is dense in $\mathcal{E}$. We say that $T$ is closed if the graph $\{(v,Tv):v\in V\}$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{E}\oplus\mathcal{E}.$
Let $T$ be the operator in Banach space $\mathcal{E}$ with the domain $D(T).$
The graph norm on $D(T)$ is the norm is defined by
$$\|v\|_T=\|v\|_{\mathcal{E}}+\|Tv\|_{\mathcal{E}}$$ for all $v\in D(T).$
How to show the graph norm above is indeed a norm on $D(T)?$ Here, $D(T)$ is the set of $\phi\in L^p(X)$ for which $A\phi$ exists.

Does anyone have a solution of the question I asked above?

Comment: Take a screenshot of your link; it's inaccessible for some of us.

Comment: I think that Kato's "Perturbation theory of linear operators" contains all required material.

Comment: @Urgie Do you know what page (or what chapter) in Kato?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use $X$ instead of $\mathcal{E}$.

Let $X$ be a normed space and $T:D(T)\to X$ a linear operator, where $D(T)$ is a linear subspace of $X$. The graph norm on $D(T)$ is given by
$$\|u\|_T^2=\|u\|_X^2+\|Tu\|_X^2$$

> *How to show the graph norm above is indeed a norm on $D(T)?$*

We have to verify the following conditions:

1. $\|u\|_T> 0$ if $u\neq 0$;
2. $\|a u\|_T=|a|\|u\|_T$ for any scalar $a$;
3. $\|u+v\|_T\leq\|u\|_T+\|v\|_T$ for any vectors $u$ and $v$ (triangle inequality).

**Proof of 1:** As $\|\cdot\|_X$ is a norm, we have $\|u\|_T^2=\|u\|_X^2+\|Tu\|_X^2\geq \|u\|_X^2>0$  if $u\neq 0$ and thus 1 is valid.

**Proof of 2:** As $T$ is linear and $\|\cdot\|_X$ is a norm, we have 
$$\|a u\|_T^2=\|a u\|_X^2+\|T(a u)\|_X^2=|a|^2\|u\|_X^2+|a|^2\|Tu\|_X^2=|a|^2\|u\|_T^2$$
for any scalar $a$ and thus 2 is valid.

**Proof of 3:**

$$\begin{align}
\|u+v\|_T^2&=\|u+v\|^2_X+\|T(u+v)\|^2_X \qquad\text{(by definition of $\|\cdot\|_T$)}\\\\
&\leq (\|u\|_X+\|v\|_X)^2+(\|Tu\|_X+\|Tv\|_X)^2\qquad\text{(by triangle inequality)}\\\\
&= \|u\|_X^2+2\|u\|_X\|v\|_X+\|v\|_X^2+\|Tu\|_X^2+2\|Tu\|_X\|Tv\|_X+\|Tv\|_X^2\\\\
&\leq\|u\|^2_X+\|Tu\|^2_X+2\sqrt{(\|u\|^2_X+\|Tu\|^2_X)(\|v\|^2_X+\|Tv\|^2_X)}+\|v\|^2_X+\|Tv\|^2_X\\\\
&=\|u\|_T^2+2\|u\|_T\|v\|_T+\|v\|_T^2\\\\
&=(\|u\|_T+\|v\|_T)^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, both of the attempts. My apology that the question I have in mind is in the context of Banach space. Hope you guys could help...

Comment: @math101 See remarks 2 and 3.

Comment: what if I consider dense subspace of $L^p$ rather than $L^2$, the inner product structure is not relevant to the context I have in mind

Comment: @math101 Sorry, I didn't understand your doubt.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't mention the book, what I asked for is just what I've written. I have edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @math101 see my last edit.

Comment: Thank you Pedro. But remark 2 is still based on that inner structure, I am looking at $L^p$, not $L^2$...See my edited question.

Comment: I am looking at your remark, and I wish to replace all those "2" with "p". But I am not sure when I get to the 3rd line. Hope you could get what I mean

Comment: @math101 Remark 2 is not based on the inner product structure. There, the first inequality follows from the triangle inequality (applied to $\|\cdot\|_X$, which do not has inner product structure) and the rest follows from some algebraic manipulation.

Comment: I get the triangle inequality bit (I think in $p$ case, one can use the minikowski inequality to show this) However, I get lost in the algebraic manipulation when considering $p$ case (need help), though I understand what you wrote for the $p=2$ case.

Comment: @math101 For the case $p\neq 2$ you can use exactly the same calculation that is in Remark 2, with $\|\cdot\|_X$ replaced by $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}$. No additional algebra is needed. The Minkowski inequality is used to pass from the first line to the second.

Comment: @math101 In general, the norm on $D(T)$ can be defined as $\|u\|_T^2=\|u\|_X^2+\|Tu\|_X^2$ or $\|u\|_T=\|u\|_X+\|Tu\|_X$. So, for the special case $X=L^p$ we have $\|u\|_T^2=\|u\|_{L^p}^2+\|Tu\|_{L^p}^2$ or $\|u\|_T=\|u\|_{L^p}+\|Tu\|_{L^p}$. We don't have $\|u\|_T^p=\|u\|_{L^p}^p+\|Tu\|_{L^p}^p$ and thus we don't have to expand the $p$ power. This is the point that is causing confusion. You are working with a "wrong" definition of the graph norm on $L^p$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my silly mistake. On $\|u\|_T^2=\|u\|_{L^p}^2+\|Tu\|_{L^p}^2$ or $\|u\|_T=\|u\|_{L^p}+\|Tu\|_{L^p}.$ When to raise to the power of 2 when not?

Comment: And indeed I should get $|u+v|_T=|u+v|_{L^p}+|T(u+v)|_{L^p}\le (|u|_{L^p}+|v|_{L^p})+(|Tu|_{L^p}+|Tv|_{L^p})=|u|_{L^p}+(|Tu|_{L^p}+|v|_{L^p}+|Tv|_{L^p}=|u|_{T}+|v|_{T}?$

Comment: @math101 The advantage of the definition with power of $2$ is that, if $\|\cdot\|_X$ is induced by an inner product then the graph norm will be induced by an inner product too. If your space $X$ doesn't have the inner product structure, then I'm not sure if the definition with power of $2$ has any advantage. For the second question: Yes, with the definition without power of $2$ the proof is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may be followed from direct computations by using definition of norm and inequality formula, i.e., Cauchy-Schwartz.

(1) Since $T$ is linear so $|0|_T^2 = |0|^2 + |T0|^2 =0 $ That is $|0|_T=0$ If $|v|_T=0$, then $|v|=0$ Hence $v=0$

(2) $|cv|_T^2 =c^2|v|^2 + c^2|Tv|^2 $ so that $|cv|_T^2=|c||v|_T$

(3) $$|v+w|_T^2 =|v+w|^2 + |Tv+Tw|^2 \leq (|v|+|w|)^2 + (|Tv|+|Tw|)^2
 = |v|_T^2 + |w|_T^2 +2|v||w| + 2|Tv||Tw|$$

So we have a claim $$ |v||w| + |Tv||Tw| \leq |v|_T|w|_T $$

Note that this is followed from these :

$$ |v|_T|w|_T =\sqrt{|v|^2|w|^2 + |Tv|^2|Tw|^2+ |v|^2|Tw|^2 + |w|^2|Tv|^2 } $$

$$ 2|v||w||Tv||Tw| \leq  |v|^2|Tw|^2 + |w|^2|Tv|^2  $$

Comment: I was asking a question in the context of Banach space. Sorry that I forgot to emphasis this...

Comment: I do not know well about the context. But I think that the first line in 239p. means that if $(V_i, |\ |_i)$ is normed space then $(V_1\times \cdots \times V_n, |\ |)$ is a normed space where $|(v_1,\cdots, v_n)|^2 =\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|_i^2$

Comment: @math101 The HKLee's answer is general (However, it seems that there is a typo). The part "Not considering Banach" means that the completeness is not needed  (I guess).

Comment: @math101 Sorry. I must consider the completeness (as Pedro said) I will edit.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I will learn about what you will write

Comment: @math101, HKLee The typo that I said is in the line (3) (where are the terms $|Tu|^2$ and $|Tv|^2$ in the last equality?). Also, HKLee was right by not considering the completeness (to clarify, I've expanded my comment on the completeness in my answer - see remark 4).